# TypeError: [(1, 73)] is not valid value for the expected return type integer, how to translate the output to [[1,73]]

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, typeerror

working on an algorithm problem and I believe I am producing the expected results however since I used a dictionary, I am having type error when I try to return the result from the dictionary. I'd appreciate any hint provided.

'''

```
class Leaderboard:

def __init__(self):
    self.players = {}
    

def addScore(self, playerId: int, score: int) -> None:
    
    if playerId not in self.players:
        self.players[playerId]=score
       
       
            
    else:
        self.players[playerId]+=score

def top(self, K: int) -> int:
    top = []
    top = dict(sorted(self.players.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)[:K])
        

    return list(top.items())
    

def reset(self, playerId: int) -> None:
   
    del self.players[playerId]
    print(self.players)
        
    obj = Leaderboard()
    #obj.addScore(1,73)
    add_score =  [[1,73],[2,56],[3,39],[1,7],[4,51],[5,4]]


    for i in range (len(add_score)):
    obj.addScore(add_score[i][0],add_score[i][1])
    print(obj.top(1))
    print(obj.reset(4))
```

## INPUT ["Leaderboard","addScore","addScore","addScore","addScore","addScore","top","reset","reset","addScore","top"][[],[1,73],[2,56],[3,39],[4,51],[5,4],[1],[1],[2],[2,51],[3]]

'''

Answer (score 0):

Either return an `int` or declare a type that matches what you want to return.  Something like this (untested):

```
def top (self, K: int) -> list(tuple(int, int)):
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but this is on leetcode and it is not possible to change the return type. Using a dictionary makes things lot easier to resolve this that's why I am trying to see if there's a way

Comment: @MikeCurtis My response was of the form, "Do X or do Y. Here is how you'd do Y." If Y is not doable, then you have to do X.

Comment: Got it and it did provide me to find a solution, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Applied below and solved the issue. Basically I am translating values in the dictionary into a list.

```
    def top(self, K: int) -> int:
        scores =  list(self.players.values())
        scores.sort(reverse=True)
   
        return sum(scores[:K])
```